# jpa criteria query duplicate values in fetched list

Tags: java, list, jpa, criteriaquery

I'm observing what I think is an unexpected behaviour in JPA 2 when fetching a list attribute with a criteria query.

My query is as follows (an extract of it):

```java
CriteriaBuilder b = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<MainObject> c = b.createQuery(MainObject.class);
Root<MainObject> root = c.from(MainObject.class);
Join<MainObject, FirstFetch> firstFetch = (Join<MainObject, FirstFetch>) root.fetch(MainObject_.firstFetch);
firstFetch.fetch(FirstFetch_.secondFetch); //secondFetch is a list
c.select(root).distinct(true);
```

(So let's say I'm fetching a list as a property of the property of an object.)

The thing is when the query returns multiple results, secondFetch values are duplicated as many times as rows are returned. Each *firstFetch* should have just one *secondFetch* but has **n** instead.
The only particularity i see in this case is all  *MainObjects* happen to have the same FirstFetch instance.
So my guess is the join is being crossed, which is normal, but then JPA fails to assign its *secondFetch* object to each one of the *firstFetchs*.

Mappings shouldn't be too special, the're more or less like this

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="mainobject")
public class MainObject{
   //...
   private FirstFetch firstFetch;

   @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name="mainObject_column")
   public FirstFetch getFirstFetch() {
    return firstFetch;
   }
}
```

and

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="firstFetch")
public class FirstFetch{
   //...
   private List<SecondFetch> secondFetch;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy="secondFetch")
   public List<SecondFetch> getSecondFetch() {
      return secondFetch;
   }
}
```

& finally

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="secondFetch")
public class SecondFetch {
    //....
    private FirstFetch firstFetch; //bidirectional

     @ManyToOne
     @JoinColumn(name="column")
     public FirstFetch getFirstFetch() {
        return firstFetch;
     }
}
```

I've been looking for some sort of **distinct** sentence to apply to the fetch but there's none (would have been a 'patch' anyway...)

If i change

```java
List<SecondFetch>
```

for

```java
Set<SecondFetch>
```

i'll get the expected result thanks to Sets' **Keys**, so I do feel this is kind of a misbehaviour in JPA's lists.

I'm not an expert, though, so i could perfectlly be making some mistake in the mappings or query.
Any feeback is very welcome to help clear this out.
Thanks.

Comment: What JPA provider are you using?  Could be a bug.

Comment: i'm using JBoss 6.1.0's default provider, which would be Hibernate 3.6.6 Final, if i'm not wrong.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem.
I'm using criteria api to fetch the (second) list like this:

     d.fetch(FirstFetch_.secondFetch, JoinType.LEFT);

Answer (score 11):

I had the exact same problem though I was using JPA criteria API to do the query.

After some research I found a solution which you already mentioned (but was not available, since your not using criteria API): Using `distinct`.

With JPA criteria it would look like this:

```
CriteriaQuery<FirstFetch> query = cb.createQuery(FirstFetch.class);
Root<AbschnittC> root = query.from(FirstFetch.class);
root.fetch(FirstFetch_.secondFetch, JoinType.LEFT);
query.distinct(true);
```

Without using `query.distinct(true);` the resultset was multiplied with the amount of objects in the `secondFetch` list.

Hibernate does have something like `DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY` which sound more adequate than just setting a query distinct. But I have not further investigated this. I am also using Hibernate as the JPA provider. Maybe setting the `query` distinct in JPA ends up using the same code as Hibernates `DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY` would?

Comment: thanks for the feedback, i'll take a look at this DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY and update as soon as possible

Comment: Your example only does one fetch(); I don't think it's the same as what's being described above.